# Attempting to learn JQuery, stuck on 2 issues

Tags: jquery

As I said, I am attempting to learn jQuery and cant seem to fix 2 issues that I'm having. The page is here: http://www.illism.com/Manny/03

1. When someone clicks the "Lounge" or the "Restaurant" links I'd like the page to scroll not just "jump" to the section. I've tried and tried and tried, to no avail...
2. I figured out how to have the hidden "sections" or "pages" (actually just divs) display on the resturant side of the page when a user clicks the "mainnav" hrefs usings this:

   ```
   $(function(){
   function contentSwitcher(settings){
       var settings = {
          contentClass: '.content',
          navigationId: '#mainnav'
       };
       $(settings.contentClass).hide();

       $(settings.navigationId).find('a').click(function(e){
           var contentToShow = $(this).attr('href');
           contentToShow = $(contentToShow).fadeTo('slow',1.0);

           e.preventDefault();

           $(settings.contentClass).hide();
           contentToShow.show();
       });
   }
   contentSwitcher();
   });
   ```

the issue I'm having is that there are technically 2 "#mainnav" and 2 sets of ".content", one in the "#restaurant" div and one in the "#lounge" div. How can I edit the script to work with both?

Comment: sorry: http://www.illism.com/Manny/03

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please post two separate questions as two separate questions.

Comment: You should delete this question and create two separate questions. Also, a question on SO should be able to stand on it's own without links to external resources such as your website. To accomplish this, create a small test-case (not your entire website/page) on jsbin.com or jsfiddle.net that recreates the problem you are trying to solve.